# The filtered result is not updated properly after editing the tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

When I go to [stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags) directly the filtering seems to work properly, but ones I remove the latest tag in the tags fields there is no result anymore. It also doesn't seems possible to re-add the tag I just removed.

After going to the link directly:
[image]

After removing the latest tag:
[image]

Re-adding the tags is impossible:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's by design. You have a non-existent tag in your query (extjs6-mod), note the red squiggles. The requests made when you're editing your tag filter are optimized for speed, and bail out early as soon as they stumble upon an invalid tag.